# How to cancel out .table width:100% in bootstrap css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have my table not take all available space. In my `bootstrap.css`, I have:

```
.table {
    width: 100%
...
```

In Chrome Dev Tools, I cancel it and the table shrinks. 

How can I override this in my CSS files without modifying the bootstrap file.
Thanks

Comment: Set `width: auto` using a rule with at least the same (if it comes after the bootstrap styles) or higher specificity …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.table {
    width: initial;
}
```

or

```
.table {
    width: unset;
}
```

does the trick.

Answer (score 5):

1. Ensure your own stylesheet is included *after* Bootstrap in your HTML.
2. Override Bootstrap's 100% `width` style declaration by setting the `.table`'s `width` to 'auto' in your stylesheet:

   ```css
   .table {
     width: auto;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

#### Option 1

If it's possible to add your CSS file AFTER your Bootstrap file, this is really all it takes :

```
.table {
    width: auto;
}
```

---

#### Option 2

If it's not possible to add your CSS file AFTER your Bootstrap file, you could increase the [**specificity**](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) like this :

```
table.table {
    width: auto;
}
```

Note that this would also work if you put this code after your Bootstrap file. Option 1 is just slightly simpler.

---

#### Option 3 (not recommended)

You could also add an `!important` declaration to your rule, which means your rule will override the Bootstrap style no matter (1) whether it's before or after your Bootstrap file, and (2) regardless of specificity :

```
.table {
    width: auto !important;
}
```

Because CSS rules with `!important` declarations can override any rule without `!important` declarations no matter where they're defined or what's their specificity, styles with lots of `!important` declarations are difficult to maintain and debug. Therefore, it is recommended to avoid using `!important`, so you should use either option 1 or option 2, depending on whether your CSS comes before or after your Bootstrap file.

Answer (score 0):

As of Bootstrap 5 (and probably earlier), you can use the Bootstrap utility class `w-auto`:

```
<table class="table w-auto">
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.table{Width :100% !important;}
```

Comment: 1. OP wants the width to **not** be 100%. 2. `!important` should always be avoided where unnecessary (which is almost always). Here it's completely unnecessary.

Comment: I thought he said that chrome was cancelling 100% and reducing the width . Hence important would solve it